# Employer info always missing on user settings within Careers

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Within SO Careers, my employer info is never shown, even after I edit it and save it.

[image]

Comment: Is it not saving the changes? Where are you expecting the data to show besides that edit screen?

Comment: Its saving the changes but dont you think the name of the employer should be next to the edit link?  The page looks to be something that has a field label and next to it a value.  All other labels such as real name, email, language, openid, and openid email show the value.  The missing piece here is the employer info...it should show the employer name at least with the edit hyperlink next to it.

Comment: I honestly have no feelings either way and it's been that way for several years. It's more for informational purposes that we use around the site.

Comment: I'll throw it up on the our feature request tracker, but it's not a bug per se.

Comment: @Juice - If you're going to create something like this it needs to be pretty standard, odd balls like this will get open tickets like this one.  my recommendation is for you guys to pull the company name..I then see it in my settings and I can then click edit if i need to manage it.